# Most Efficient Way to Find Last Occurrence of a Character in a Given Range

Tags: javascript, string

I’m fairly new to JavaScript and need to find an efficient way to get the index of the last occurrence of a space character within a given range.  I’m not sure if this could be done with RegEx or not; I’m currently doing it with the built in string methods, however, building a new string with the substring method seems like a waste for what I need.

My current solution:

Let n be the end of the range

```
    let spaceIndex = stringText.substr(0, n + 1).lastIndexOf(" ");
```

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? What is the benchmark for the above code vs. the benchmark you need to achieve?

Comment: I’m building a package for Atom and this line of code will be ran for every row of text in the editor, so it seems like it would be pretty bad to create hundreds of strings, with the substring method, just to use it to limit the range I need to search in.

Comment: "seems like it might be inefficient" is a very poor reason to optimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use the second argument to [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf#Syntax) -- `fromIndex`:

```
let spaceIndex = stringText.lastIndexOf(" ", n + 1)
```

Comment: This seems like the ideal solution.  I didn’t realize it had an optional parameter.  Thank you.

Comment: This code also performs better according to some actual testing as well.  Again, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change your code (except for the suggestion by Adiga). What you are doing is fine and "seems like a waste" is never a good reason to optimize code.

See this [SO Software Engineering discussion on premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Code should be clear first, and only optimized if and when you run into problems. Your code looks clear to me.

Comment: The advice to go with readable code is good advice. I went with georg's solution. His is not only more readable to me, but based on online JS benchmark testers, it is significantly faster than chaining the methods together, as I did.

Comment: That's a good solution! I did not know about the 2nd arg to `lastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead of [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> Although `String.prototype.substr()` is not strictly deprecated, it is considered a legacy function and should be avoided when possible. It is not part of the core JavaScript language and may be removed in the future.

Other than that, your code looks fine

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I’m certain I’ve used the deprecated call before, so this is informative.